# c++ unordered_map compiling issue with g++

Tags: c++, hashtable, unordered-map

I am using g++ in Ubuntu

> g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

I have this code

```
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;

bool ifunique(char *s){
  unordered_map<char,bool> h;
  if(s== NULL){
    return true;
  }
  while(*s){
    if(h.find(*s) != h.end()){
      return false;
    }
    h.insert(*s,true);
    s++;
  }
  return false;
}
```

when I compile using

```
g++ mycode.cc
```

I got error

```
 error: 'unordered_map' was not declared in this scope
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In GCC 4.4.x, you should only have to `#include <unordered_map>`, and compile with this line:

`g++ -std=c++0x source.cxx`

More information about [C++0x support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

**edit regarding your problem**

You have to do `std::make_pair<char, bool>(*s, true)` when inserting.

Also, your code would only insert a single character (the dereferencing via `*s`). Do you intend to use a single `char` for a key, or did you mean to store strings?

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_map<char, bool, std::hash<char>, std::equal_to<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, bool> > >::insert(char&, bool)'

Comment: @xlione: Can you show us the code? It seems like you're trying to insert a reference type into your map.

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 
is the latest one now

Comment: i have check there is no need for pair while insertion, normally it will work.... like mp[i]=j; where mp is object of unordered_map.

Answer (score 21):

If you don't want to to compile in C++0x mode, changing the include and using directive to

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
using namespace std::tr1;
```

should work